# Add alias/prefix to existing XML namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

How can I convert the following XML

```
<root xmlns:xyz="do/not/change" xmlns="add/alias">
   <name>Test</name>
   <xyz:id>100<xyz:id>
</root>
```

To

```
<abc:root xmlns:xyz="do/not/change" xmlns:abc="add/alias">
   <abc:name>Test</abc:name>
   <xyz:id>100<xyz:id>
</abc:root>
```

Using XDocument in C#

Effectively, I want to add an alias to the second namespace, and add the prefix to all elements that do not already have a prefix.

All the information I can find is how to remove or add a namespace, but nothing about how to add a prefix/alias.

Comment: From an *information* perspective, they both carry exactly the same information. It generally shouldn't matter *what* prefixes are being used since they only have *local* meaning.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann Sorry If I am not understanding the linked question properly but that seems to handle creating a new XDocument with an alias namespace, it doesn't (as far as I can tell) explain how I can replace a namespace with an alias'ed one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am aware that it is the same, however we need to generate XMLs to submit to a third party system. They're system unfortunately only accepts the XMLs in the second format in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
var xml = @"<root xmlns:xyz='do/not/change' xmlns='add/alias'>
   <name>Test</name>
   <xyz:id>100</xyz:id>
</root>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var xn = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
xdoc.Root.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xmlns + "abc", xn.NamespaceName);
xdoc.Root.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();

foreach (var el in xdoc.Root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    if (el.Name.Namespace == xn)
    {
        el.Name = xn + el.Name.LocalName;
    }
}
```

Note that this code will break if there is no default namespace defined.

You can add a check like:

```
if (xn.NamespaceName == string.Empty) ...
```

Note 2: technically even attributes can have namespaces, like `xyz:myattr="Hello"`. We are skipping this.

Comment: For readability, you could you single quotation marks in `xml` :)

Comment: @JohnyL I normally don't use them and I started from the xml given by OP. But yes, doubling the double quotes doesn't help the readability of an xml :-)

Comment: Gave you +1, but... messing with prefixes is a mess :D

Comment: For instance, Word's XML uses `w` prefix all over document XML, but Excel uses default namespace. I wonder why this is so...

Comment: By the way, you mentioned about prefixes in attributes, but there's caveat: until attribute is assigned prefix, it *does not* belong to any namespace.